# Convert Spanish date to timestamp with Intl (PHP)

Tags: php, date, intl

I need to convert date written in the natural language to timestamp or any other standard date format. Dates are in four languages: English,  German,  French, and Spanish.
I can convert all except Spanish date with `Intl` extension.

Example of date in natural languages:

```
// es - 19 de julio de 2017
// fr - 2 février 2018
// en - May 16, 2016
// de - 27 Juni 2018
```

French date parse works fine

```
$df = \IntlDateFormatter::create(
    'fr_FR',
    \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
    \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    'Europe/Kiev'
);

$timestamp = $df->parse('2 fevrier 2018'); // 1517518800
```

But Spanish, return `false`

```
$df = \IntlDateFormatter::create(
    'es_ES',
    \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
    \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    'Europe/Kiev'
);

$timestamp = $df->parse('19 de julio de 2017'); // false
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have used `de` in your date.

```
$timestamp = $df->parse('19 julio 2017'); // false
echo $timestamp;
```

output is

> 1500411600

will work perfectly.

Comment: Yes, it works but I get a date from Amazon and in the future, we will work with all Amazon marketplaces and it will be good parse a date without preparation.